# Why do I get the 'No origination entities available to send' error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am setting up SNS to be able to send text messages to myself from Lambda. I am trying to add a (USA) phone number to SNS Sandbox, and I am getting the following message:

> An error occurred while attempting to add a phone number to the SMS sandbox. The phone number was not added.
>
> Error code: UserError - Error message: No origination entities available to send

What exactly does this mean and how can I resolve this? I looked up the error message and found nothing similar.

Answer (score 10):

This means that there is no number available to your account to send an SMS *from*. SNS calls this an origination entity.

You can find the different types of origination entities that can be used to deliver SMS to the U.S. here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-originating-identities-origination-numbers.html#sns-10dlc-product-comparison. The easiest to set up is a toll-free number, but if you're a business, you probably want a 10DLC.

This used to require zero setup in the past (SNS had a number of shared phone numbers customers could use to send from), but recently regulatory changes no longer allow sharing phone numbers in this way.

Comment: I added a toll free sms number and still get this error on mine. The instructions on there suck - error includes no links to fix or diagnose the issue.