# Stuck on AWS Pinpoint SNS Destination Verification/Originating Identities

Tags: amazon-sns, aws-pinpoint

Attempting to set up AWS Pinpoint SNS for promotional text.
It is in sandbox mode.
I requested a TFN (U.S., us-east-1), and registered it - registration status is “pending.”
To test from sandbox, I am attempting to verify a destination number, and get the following error:
“Failed to send verification code. No origination entities available.”(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZz0o.jpg)

Checked all settings, no other errors. Documentation says sandbox should work while TFN registration is pending.

I am unable to find help through search or AWS documentation.
Anyone able to give me a hand up?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get the 'No origination entities available to send' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72262975/why-do-i-get-the-no-origination-entities-available-to-send-error)

Comment: Thank you Ermiya. I requested a TFN and submitted the registration. The “status” is “pending”; but although documentation says can use it in sandbox, I get that error message. Am I missing the process of linking the two?